# Bash - read -u 3 inside while not working

Tags: bash

I am trying to run a read command inside a while loop to get user input as shown below:

```
for dir in ./*; do   
    for subdir in $dir/*; do   
        someprocess |  
        sort_processed_pipedout |  
        tail_sortedout |  
        while read line; do   
            another_process on $line  
            read -t 1 -n 10000 discard   
            read -u 3 -p "Save as final? (y/n)" USER_INPUT  
            if [ "$USER_INPUT" = y ]; then   
                                something_else  
                echo "success"  
            fi  
        done 3<&0  
    done  
done
```

This is what I think I am doing:

For every line of the tail output (basically one filename per line) the first read ignores any inadvertent input, second read switches the 'file handle' to 3 from 0 (as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9651746/bash-read-inside-a-loop-reading-a-file)) and the rest proceeds as usual.

Here's what happens:
USER_INPUT seems to come directly from the tail output.

Why does this fail?

EDIT : How do I  make it output to the same sub shell?

Comment: As you are piping, the processes belong to different sub shells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) -- and if you want to redirect stdin, you need to do so earlier, while it's still pointing to the terminal, not after it's pointing to the output from the pipeline. Better not to do that at all, though, and just put what's otherwise your pipeline on a separate FD:

```
for subdir in ./*/*; do   
    while read -r -u 3 line; do   
        : another_process on "$line"
        read -t 1 -n 10000 discard   
        read -p "Save as final? (y/n)" user_input
        if [[ $user_input = y ]]; then
            : something_else  
            echo "success"  
        fi  
    done 3< <(someprocess | sort_processed_pipeout | tail_sortedout)
done
```

Comment: Thanks! I did manage to hack my script by directing output/input to /dev/tty. This seems like a better solution though, because I don't know enough to guess if forcing it to go to /dev/tty is safe(r).

Comment: If you have access to /dev/tty, it's a fine approach safety-wise; it's just not always there. The other thing this approach does is lets you make changes to the shell's state (setting variables, running cd, etc) inside of the while loop that doesn't get thrown away when the while loop ends and the subshell it was running inside exits, by putting the rest of the pipeline into a subshell but leaving the loop itself in the outer shell.

Answer (score 1):

`0` represents the *current* standard input, not necessarily the terminal, so you are still just copying the pipe from `tail` to file descriptor 3. Move the redirection down to the next loop.

```
for dir in ./*; do   
    for subdir in $dir/*; do   
        someprocess |  
        sort_processed_pipedout |  
        tail_sortedout |  
        while read line; do   
            another_process on $line  
            read -t 1 -n 10000 discard   
            read -u 3 -p "Save as final? (y/n)" USER_INPUT  
            if [ "$USER_INPUT" = y ]; then   
                                something_else  
                echo "success"  
            fi  
        done  
    done   3<&0
done
```

(Charles Duffy's answer has some more nice improvements, so I would go with that instead of this minimal fix.)